# SMTP Config in SecureSocial for live.com

Tags: playframework, smtp, securesocial

I had configured my `SecureSocial` module in `Play 2.0.4` for a `SMTP` email transfer. If I try my configuration with Gmail it works:

```
smtp {
    host=smtp.gmail.com
    #port=25
    ssl=true
    user="user@gmail.com"
    password="password"
    from="user@gmail.com" 
}
```

But if I try it with live.com (they use the same port) it doesn't work?

Comment: Are you sure of your live.com configuration credentials? The Mailer Plugin used by SecureSocial works out fine.

Answer (score 1):

I stumble on same issue. This is my solution. Just set the smtp config to the following code

```
smtp {
    host=smtp.live.com
    port=587
    tls=true
    user=<your email>
    password=<your password>
    from=<your email>
}
```

Mind the `tls=true` part instead of `ssl=true`

Hope it helps!